# How to find character frequency in a 2D character array?

Tags: java, arrays, character, frequency

I am trying to create a program that searches through an array of characters. If there is a character that repeats itself, it should be shown.

I've tried creating a triple loop
1 to go through the the character array, and then 2 remaining ones to compare each letter with each other

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    char [][] tab = new char[][]{
        {'S','a','m','s','u','n','g'},
        {'N','o','k','i','a'},
        {'A','p','p','l','e'},
        {'B','l','a','c','k','B','e','r','r','y'},
        {'A','l','c','a','t','e','l'},
        {'S','o','n','y'},
        {'J','o','l','l','a'}};

    Litery(tab);
}

public static void Litery(char tab[][])
{
    int[] freq = new int[tab.length];  
    int counter=0;
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        int size = tab[i].length;
        for(int j=0;i<tab.length;i++)
        {
            counter=0;
            freq[i] = 1;
            for(int z = j+1;z<tab[j].length;z++)
            {
                if(tab[j] == tab[z])
                {
                    freq[i]++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<tab.length;i++)
    {
        if(freq[i] > 1)
        {
            System.out.println(tab[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I want the ouputs to be 
SAMSUNG
APPLE
BLACBERRY
ALCATEL
JOLLA
Capitalisation doesn't matter
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why should the K in Blac**k**Berry not be printed?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question correctly. If you want to calculate frequency of character in entire 2D array then `k` in `Nokia` also appears in `{'B','l','a','c','k','B','e','r','r','y'}` so shouldn't `Nokia` be printed as result? For now it doesn't look like you want to search letter in entire 2D array, but in same row which is simply checking frequency in 1D array.

Comment: @Andreas sorry, I must've mistyped.

Comment: @Pshemo Sorry if the question wasn't clear. I was trying to find if a character was repeating inside of a word (as 's' repeats twice in 'Samsung'.

Comment: Fell free to [edit] your question and clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a hash map whose keys are values in your array and values are num times that value has appeared.

1. Start with an empty map
2. Iterate through your array and for each `char`

   - get a lowercase version of the `char` since you're case-insensitive
   - if the map *does not* have a key with that char, add an entry (`char`, 1) to your map
   - otherwise, increment the number associated with `char` in your map

If you need the list of characters that appear more than once, you can iterate through your map and filter out the characters whose values are 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print "rows" (aka words) that has at least one duplicate character (case-insensitive), then you can do it easily with some stream logic in Java 8+:

```
public static void Litery(char tab[][]) {
    Stream.of(tab)
          .filter(w -> w.length != new String(w).toUpperCase().chars().distinct().count())
          .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

*Output*

```
Samsung
Apple
BlackBerry
Alcatel
Jolla
```

---

Of course, it might make more sense if the input was an actual `String[]`, so it can support characters from the supplementary planes, e.g. emoticons:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Litery("Samsung", "Nokia", "Apple", "BlackBerry", "Alcatel", "Sony", "Jolla",
           "", "");
}
public static void Litery(String... tab) {
    Stream.of(tab)
            .filter(w -> w.codePointCount(0, w.length()) != w.toUpperCase().codePoints().distinct().count())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

*Output*

```
Samsung
Apple
BlackBerry
Alcatel
Jolla
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a `int` array for checking the frequency, just initialize a boolean array of size of `tab` which is by initialized to an array of `false` values.

Now in the inner loop compare the `char` by lower-casing both character as you want to check irrespective of the case:

```
public static void Litery(char tab[][]) {
        boolean[] freq = new boolean[tab.length];
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < tab[i].length; j++){
                for (int z = 0; z < tab[i].length; z++) {
                    if (j != z && Character.toLowerCase(tab[i][j]) == Character.toLowerCase(tab[i][z])) {
                        freq[i] = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
            if (freq[i]) {
                System.out.println(tab[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

You can also avoid using three loops by using a `Set`, simply convert the array of `char` for each row in a `Set<Character>` of lowercase, if the value is repeated the resulting `Set<Character>` will be of size less than the array as `Set` does not contain duplicates:

```
public static void Litery(char tab[][]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++){
        final int idx  = i;
        if(IntStream.range(0, tab[idx].length)
                .mapToObj(j -> tab[idx][j])
                .map(Character::toLowerCase)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet()).size() != tab[i].length){
           System.out.println(String.valueOf(tab[i]));
        }
 }
```

Output:

```
Samsung
Apple
BlackBerry
Alcatel
Jolla
```

Comment: Why cast `tab[idx][j]` to `char`, when it's already a `char`?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!